# Can't read non-English characters from text file - android app

Tags: android-studio, character, hebrew

I'm trying to read data from a text file containing Hebrew characters but it shows gibberish instead.
both in the Android Studio application on debug mode and the phone it self opening it with ***ES Note Editor*** or ***HTML Viewer***.

On the computer I can open the text file with ***Notepad*** or ***Notepad++*** and it displays the characters fine.

Is there sort of compatible format for that?

Comment: `compatible format` pdf?

Comment: How can you read from pdf on java?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like format UTF-8 solves the problem..

Just open the text file with Notepad,
 File-> Save As

and make sure Encoding at the bottom is set to `UTF-8`